# $_POST variables not seen after mod_rewrite on same domain

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-post

I've recently inherited a site (originally created ca. 2008) from another agency and I've been able to get most of it moved over to an Amazon Linux server running on Amazon EC2 with Apache 2.4.12 and PHP 5.5.24.

One pernicious problem, though, is that no `$_POST` form data is seen by pages rewritten via rewrite rules in `.htaccess.` To troubleshoot, I put in PHP code to dump `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_SERVER`, and `$_SESSION` before *anything* else in the page loads, and I'm seeing NULL or empty arrays for each. A simple form/handler that is not affected by `.htaccess` sees the form data easily.

The forms are all on the same domain, and forms work on the original site (unfortunately I cannot request their `php.ini` or other configurations, but I can post what I have if it helps).

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Thanks in advance for helping me figure out my first question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just making sure: If you're trying to access to file directly [with post data] (while temporally removing the htaccess file) - does `$_POST` shows values?

Comment: What does one of your form links look like?

Comment: Ofir: if I remove the .htaccess file and post data directly to index.php, it shows up. It's when the form data is sent to /some-htaccess-rewriten-address that the POST data is stripped;  

Panama Jack: I suppose it's ok if I post the link to a form on the existing site [link](http://cport.net/fish-online/login) and the soon-to-be replacement [link](http://52.24.12.130/fish-online/login). You'll see my troubleshooting output right at the top of the page. A page that bypasses .htaccess is [here](http://52.24.12.130/formtest.php)

Thanks, both!

Comment: Are `fish-online/login` real directories?

Comment: This is not mod_rewrite-related, or at least not on a default installation. POST-data is stripped if a redirect takes place, but $_SERVER should not be empty or NULL in any case. Besides that, the code in your .htaccess file does not perform a redirect. Your framework might perform a redirect, but you should inspect that in the browser.

Comment: fish-online/login is not a real directory. It's passed to the framework which renders the page correctly (Haven't been able to delve into the code fully to figure out how. It doesn't seem to be rewritten as a $_GET variable in the .htaccess file, yet it works.). I understand that the framework itself might unset the global variables itself, but I find it strange that this would be the case before ANYTHING else is loaded at all.

Comment: I found an interesting thing that solves the problem, but doesn't QUITE answer the question. When I use a fully qualified domain name instead of an IP address, it all works. I imagine the framework is reading the URL directly and rendering the page from there (though I still can't see POST variables).  

  Should I mark this as an answer?